# Angular 2: How to handle async errors from services in components?

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say we have a service that does an http call to an API to create an user. Based on the result (200 or error) the app should redirect or display the errors (there are some Validations going on client-side, but that is not the topic since validations should always also happen server-side).

The Angular 2 docs state that it is bad practice to let the service return an observable and subscribe to it in the component. The service should be self-contained and the component shouldn't need to know anything about this. It should be enough to call `userService.createUser(user_data);`

But then again routing should happen in the component. So I'm wondering how to handle this situation? Should my Service return a new Observable? Or just a value? But then how do I deal with the async task?

What is the right way to do this?

Let's take this service to create a user and this component as an example:

`// user.service.ts:`

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { API_CONFIG, Config } from '../config/api.config';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  validation_errors: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
    @Inject(API_CONFIG) private api_config: Config,
    private http: Http,
    @Inject(User) public user: User
  ) {}

  createUser(user: User) {
    var body = JSON.stringify({ user });
    var myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post(this.api_config.apiEndpoint + '/users/', body, { headers: myHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          // User was created successfully
          this.user = this.fromJson(res.data);
        },
        err => {
          // Something went wrong, let's collect all errors in a class attribute
          let errors = err.json().errors;
          for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            this.validation_errors.push(errors[i])
          }
        }
      );
  }

  /**
  * @param input_json JSON returned from API, formatted according to jsonapi.org, containing one single user.
  * @return UserModel instantiated with the values from input_json
  */
  fromJson(input_json: any) {
    var user:User = new User();
    user = input_json.attributes;
    user.id = input_json.id;
    return user;
  }
}
```

`// user.component.ts:`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { UserService } from '../../shared/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-user-editor',
  templateUrl: 'app/+users/editor/user-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/+users/editor/user-editor.component.css'],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  // Setup Form
  private email_regex = '[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+@[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+';
  userForm: FormGroup;
  action: string;
  idCtrl = new FormControl('');
  nameCtrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  emailCtrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.email_regex)]);
  usernameCtrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]);
  passwordCtrl = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(8)]);
  passwordConfirmationCtrl = new FormControl('');

  public user_id: string;


  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private params: RouteParams) {}

  /**
  * Handle submit of form
  */
  onSubmit(form: any) {
    // Here should happen some error handling / routing, depending on the result of the call to the API
    this.userService.createUser(this.userService.user);
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {

    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      id: this.idCtrl,
      name: this.nameCtrl,
      email: this.emailCtrl,
      username: this.usernameCtrl,
      password: this.passwordCtrl,
      password_confirmation: this.passwordConfirmationCtrl
    });

  }

}
```

I could display the error messages in the template like this:

```
<div class="form-group"
  [hidden]="adminService.validation_errors.length === 0"
  class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  <strong>Some errors occured</strong>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let validation_error of adminService.validation_errors">
      <span class="text-capitalize">{{validation_error.source.field}}:</span> {{validation_error.detail}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example would work, but what if someone else (maybe another service?) uses the `adminService` and creates an error? Your component would display that error to right?

Comment: @Springrbua: My example is a bad example how it should not be done (even though it works). I would like to refactor it, using Observables, while following the best practice guidelines by google.

Comment: You could pass an empty Array `validation_errors` to the method and fill it with the errors, so that every call returns it's own results. You could also use callback functions, but as much as i remember Angular2 uses `Observables`, among others because they are easier to read than x levels of callbacks... I myself use `Observable`s and subscribe to them. I can't see any reason why you shouldn't use them in components. I mean Angular2 has an `async` `Pipe` which was made for `Observable`s and `Promis`es

Comment: I don't really see how pipes would help me with async error handling. Could you give an example of returning an Observable?

Comment: I just wanted to say, that angular2 provides a pipe made for observables (the async pipe). So i dont understand why you shouldnt use observables in your component.

Comment: I am not sure but i guess that the async pipe allows error handling to... AsyncPipe Docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. My service now uses .map() to transform the data (JSON) returned from the backend and returns an Observable which will initialise my User Model. The Component can subscribe to the observable. The data is stored in a variable of the component, as well as the validation errors.

I also use FormBuilder form the new Form API. This should work with RC 3.

I hope this helps someone.

`// user.service.ts:`

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { API_CONFIG, Config } from '../config/api.config';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(API_CONFIG) private api_config: Config,
    private http: Http,
    @Inject(User) public user: User
  ) {}

  createUser(user: User) {
    var body = JSON.stringify({ user });
    var myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // Use map to transform reply from server (JSON to User Object) and return an Observable 
    // The component can subscribe to.
    return this.http.post(this.api_config.apiEndpoint + '/users/', body, { headers: myHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        return this.fromJson(res.data);
      });

  }

  /**
  * @param input_json JSON returned from API, formatted according to jsonapi.org, containing one single user.
  * @return UserModel instantiated with the values from input_json
  */
  fromJson(input_json: any) {
    var user:User = new User();
    user = input_json.attributes;
    user.id = input_json.id;
    return user;
  }
}
```

`// user.component.ts:`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
// Include the User Model
import { User, UserService } from '../../shared/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-user-editor',
  templateUrl: 'app/+users/editor/user-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/+users/editor/user-editor.component.css'],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [User, UserService]
})
export class UserEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  // Setup Form
  private email_regex = '[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+@[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+';
  userForm: FormGroup;
  validation_errors: Array<string> = [];
  user_id: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private user: User, private router: Router, private params: RouteParams, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  /**
  * Handle submit of form
  */
  onSubmit(form: any) {
    // Subscribe to observable and handle errors
    this.userService.createUser(this.userService.user).subscribe(
      user => {
        // Store created user in Component variable. We could now display it or navigate somewhere
        this.user = user;
      },
      err => {
        let errors = err.json().errors;
        for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
          // Handle errors in the component and don't store it in the Service
          this.validation_errors.push(errors[i])
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    // Use the new FormBuilder
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [''],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.email_regex)]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      password_confirmation: ['']
    });

  }

}
```

`user-editor.component.html`

```
<div class="form-group"
  [hidden]="validation_errors.length === 0"
  class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  <strong>Some errors occured</strong>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let validation_error ofvalidation_errors">
      <span class="text-capitalize">{{validation_error.source.field}}:</span> {{validation_error.detail}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```